# Compare two files in Sublime Text 3

Tags: compare, sublimetext3

I am not able to compare two files in sublime text 3. I have selected the two files I want to compare, however there is no Diff File option when searching for option through right click..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to install a package such as:

Sublimerge, FileDiffs, Diffy between others.

Once you have it installed, just follow the instructions of the creator.

Useful links:

https://www.slant.co/topics/2030/~best-diff-plugins-for-sublime-text

https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Compare%20Side-By-Side

Answer (score 2):

Use third party software [Code Compare](https://www.devart.com/codecompare/) to compare code file and whole project.